# How to express $\log_2 (\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{5})$ in terms of $k=\log_2 (\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{5})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $$k=\log_2 (\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{5})$$
express $\log_2 (\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{5})$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: Hint: $\log_2(9-5)=\log_2((\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5}))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the logarithms $\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}$ and $\log_2{(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5})}$ we get the following:

$$\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}+\log_2{(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5})}=\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5})}=\log_2{(9-5)}=\log_2{4}=\log_2{2^2}=2 \cdot \log_2{2}=2$$

Knowing that $k=\log_2{(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5})}$ we have:

$$\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}+\log_2{(\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{5})}=\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}+k$$

Therefore, $$2=\log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}+k \Rightarrow \log_2{(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{5})}=2-k$$

Answer (score 2):

Add to both sides the term $\log_2 (\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{5})$, then you have
$$
\log_2 (\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{5}) + k = \log_2 (4),
$$
so that
$$
\log_2 (\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{5}) = 2 - k. 
$$

Comment: Add not multiply.

Comment: Yuck, what a blunder. Thanks.

Comment: The answer from the text book is 2(2-k)

Comment: @BillyTeo well the textbook is wrong.